# Sticky random connection failure while trying to get variable

Tags: java, oracle, camunda

I have a web application that is being tested for a while on customer's servers. Everything works fine until something triggers a sticky exception that raises only in certain situations (exact ui page, each time random). From it's stacktrace, exception is caused by broken connection to a database (`ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found`), but I can't figure out why - other pages work fine with same db query patterns.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:245) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130) ~[spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:40) ~[camunda-engine-spring-7.2.0.jar:7.2.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:32) ~[camunda-engine-7.2.0.jar:7.2.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.RuntimeServiceImpl.getVariablesTyped(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:172) ~[camunda-engine-7.2.0.jar:7.2.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.RuntimeServiceImpl.getVariables(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:168) ~[camunda-engine-7.2.0.jar:7.2.0]
at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.RuntimeServiceImpl.getVariables(RuntimeServiceImpl.java:60) ~[camunda-engine-7.2.0.jar:7.2.0]
at kz.primesource.platform.blocks.util.function.BpmUtil.processVariables(BpmUtil.java:41) ~[platform-blocks-bpm-camunda-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor815.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at de.odysseus.el.tree.impl.ast.AstFunction.invoke(AstFunction.java:113) ~[juel-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
at de.odysseus.el.tree.impl.ast.AstFunction.eval(AstFunction.java:120) ~[juel-impl-2.2.7.jar:2.2.7]
... 83 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:204) ~[spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
... 96 common frames omitted

Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:399) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.4.0.jar:11.2.0.4.0]
... 107 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Maybe the maximal connections/processes of the oracle database are exceeded?

Comment: @SebastianMenski As it turned out, we indeed had connection pool problem - instead of pooled data source we were using DriverManagerDataSource. Please create an answer out of this comment so I could accept it in case if somebody else will encounter the same problem.